# 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'tree_'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import tree

rf = RandomForestClassifier()

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
n_nodes = rf.tree_.node_count
```

Everytime I run this code, I get the following error

> 'RandomForestClassifier' object has no attribute 'tree_'

any ideas why

Comment: I'd guess because `tree_` isn't an attribute of that class.

Comment: tree_ is an attribute of underlying trees in the forest which you can access by using `estimators_`. Then you need to iterate each estimator and then call tree_ on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), it doesn't have `.tree_`  attribute.

It only has: `estimators_`, `classes_`, `n_classes_`, `n_features_`, `n_outputs_`, `feature_importances_`, `oob_score_`, and `oob_decision_function_` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You want to pull a single `DecisionTreeClassifier` out of your forest. From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), `base_estimator_` is a `DecisionTreeClassifier` and `estimators_` is a list of `DecisionTreeClassifier`. The change to your code is:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import tree

rf = RandomForestClassifier()

rf.fit(X_train, y_train)

n_nodes = rf.base_estimator_.tree_.node_count
  or
n_nodes = rf.estimators_[0].tree_.node_count
```

Answer (score 0):

**'tree_'** is not RandomForestClassifier attribute. It is the attribute of DecisionTreeClassifiers.

You should not use this while using RandomForestClassifier, there is no need of it.